In C++11 memory model，read/write same event fd can established Synchronizes with relastionship？
I'm writting a eventfd based mpsc lockless message queue,the simply code like this:
//producter thread
auto prev = head_.exchange(std::memory_order_acq_rel);
prev.next_.store(head_, std::memory_order_release); // (1)
bool expected = false;
if(notified_.compare_exchange_strong(expected, true, std::memory_order_acq_rel)){ // (2)
    //write event fd 2)
}
//consumer thread
//read event fd... 
notified_.exchange(false, std::memory_order_acq_rel); // (3)
//read head .. (4)

according the c++ 11 memory model:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order
my question is:
a)read and write same event fd can established Synchronizes with relationship, make 1 happens before 4? as the standard says：

Also, some library calls may be defined to synchronize-with other library calls on other threads.

b) if not, (3) and (2) can established Synchronizes with relationship?
c) or must alter consumer thread as blew to meet Synchronizes with ？
//consumer thread
//read event fd... 
while(!notified_.load(std::memory_order_acq_rel)){// (3)   
}
notified_.store(false, std::momory_order_release);
//read head .. (4)


It's hard to figure out what you are asking. Are you asking if the read and write themselves synchronise, or are you asking whether the use of atomics in your examples guards the read and write such that there isn't a data race?
